# Перенос сайта с хостинга на VPS

Tags: хостинг, vps

Всем привет! Сайт набрал аудиторию, которую хостинг просто не выдерживает, следовательно, нужно переходить на более мощное оборудование. Произвожу и содержу сайт в одиночку, а дальше хостинга не использовал.Что хотелось бы узнать: Сайт-сервис, на нем постоянно загружаются новые файлы и база данных успешно быстро растет. Как использовать в такой ситуации - отдельно хостинг только с сайтом, а с помощью FTP работать с VPS? А где хранить базу данных? Мне хотелось бы узнать, как популярные сайты работают? В интернете подобной информации не нашел. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Про файлы. В зависимости от посещаемости сайта могут быть разные подходы. Когда реально много файлов загружается, выгружается (видео, картинки и т.п.), то их удобно хранить просто в файловой системе (xfs и т.п.), а в базе данных держать только пути к этим файлам. Если количество и объем этих файлов велики, можно выделить под них отдельный сервер, который только и будет отдавать эти файлы.

Про базу данных. В зависимости от ее типа (SQL/NoSQL, диск, память и т.п.) и размера ее может быть удобно хранить и на отдельном сервере. Однако в этом случае может стать узким местом само физическое соединение с сервером базы данных. Плюс каждый новый сервер - это дополнительные деньги.

Comment: Будет хорошим вариантом - использовать обычный хостинг для самого сайта, а уже VPS использовать для базы данных и для файлов?

Comment: А что вы называете обычным хостингом?

Comment: Виртуальный хостинг за 200-500 руб.

Comment: Особого смысла делить нет, только если они не будут сильно различно сконфигурированы: то есть на одном много места, на другом памяти. А так у вас от VPS с запасом должно остаться ресурса.

Comment: То есть, использовать VPS так же, как и дешевый виртуальный хостинг? Все хранить на VPS?